# How to add an additional label to each address form field in Prestashop 1.7.7.0?

Tags: label, field, prestashop-1.7

I am using Prestashop version 1.7.7.0.

How to add an additional label to each address form field? I see from form-fields.tpl that the fields labels are retrieved by $field.label. It is possible to add a property like $field.label2? If so where?

The additional label will be displayed as a "helper" string near the field.

Example:
[image]